# If-else populate field error in Python (arcpy)

Tags: python, if-statement, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to learn python and writing an arcpy script for ArcGIS 10.1.

The objective is to check a variety of fields for a -99 value which specifies NULL and then populate the newly added field with a 0 value. The code runs...however it populates all values with a 6 value. The 6 is part of the problem, the other part being that I've checked and there should only be 3 (-99) values in the table.

Below is the code:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

print "start your engines"
# Script arguments
Shapefile = "C:\\gislab2\\Python\\take_home\\USCancer2000.shp"
#this is where the arcpy.userargument part goes, get from re-exporting model.
Field_Name = "Henry1"

Output_Feature_Class = "C:\\gislab2\\Python\\take_home\\USCancer2000.shp"

# Local variables:
USCancer2000__2_ = Output_Feature_Class

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(Shapefile, "Henry1", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "Henry1", "5.5", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
##
### Process: If-then check for missing values
##
if "Cnt1"==-99:
    Field_name=0
elif "Cnt2"==-99:
    Field_name=0
elif "Cnt3"==-99:
    Field_name=0
elif "Pop1"==-99:
    Field_name==0
elif "Pop2"==-99:
    Field_name=0
elif "Pop3"==-99:
    Field_name=0
```

Answer (score 4):

Gabriel's comments are valid, but the main problem is that you're not looping through the rows in your feature class - you can't just go `if "Cnt1" == -99` and expect Python to know that it should look at the `Cnt1` field in every row of a feature class.

What you need in this case is an [Update cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000), which will look at each row of the feature class in turn, and allow you to update field values. Something like this should get you moving:

```
fields = ['Cnt1','Cnt2','Cnt3','Pop1','Pop2','Pop3']

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Output_Feature_Class)
for row in cursor:
    for field in fields:
        if row.getValue(field) == -99:
            row.setValue(Field_Name, 0)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing to constants in your code.

is "Cnt1"==-99 ??

that will never be True.

I do not know Arcpy, but if you want to parse some results from its functions you should get some returned value or inspect variables passed as parameters after the call.

Comment: Gabriel, I'm a little unclear as to your suggestion; Cnt1 is a field with various values, not a function; can a field be used in an if-elif statement? or does the if-elif need to be within a function which is then called to check the field with the if-elif statement?

Comment: a "field" that you refer in programming is called a variable.

"Cnt1" isn't a variable, "Cnt1" is a constant that have string type. So, in python you can change the values of variables like that:
Cnt1 = 99 

and not "Cnt1"